# Leafet.js: add button with link to zoombox function

Tags: leaflet

I need to add a control button with a "rectangle" zoom or what's called the boxZoom function in leaflet. I know that the function can be used when pressing shift and drawing a rectangle but I need a button that gets clicked and then the user can draw a rectangle which is used a bounds for the boxZoom function. I thought this wouldn't be difficult but I just can't figure it out.

Bonus points if you could tell me how to link other functions, e.g. of leaflet.draw, to my own buttons. I need to create my own button toolbar, so I need to be able to attach different functions to the buttons and would like to use already existing functions.

Comment: Recently found on Github: [L.Control.BoxZoom](https://github.com/gregallensworth/L.Control.BoxZoom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a one size fits all solution for this (thus the reason for L.Control.BoxZoom being its own plugin). You'll need to add buttons with click handlers, then read the API of Leaflet or the plugin you're integrating with (e.g. drawing) to find how to toggle the behavior.

The [Leaflet.EasyButton](http://cliffcloud.github.io/Leaflet.EasyButton/v1/) plugin does a good job of encapsulating the creation of single button controls and click handlers in an easy way, and may be a good starting point if you're struggling with getting started.